# A Java web project created with Maven is not recognized as such by Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, maven

I created a web project with maven like this:

`mvn archetype:create -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-webapp -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp`

Then I run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` so that an eclipse project is built. Eclipse recognizes all the features of the project but it doesn't recognize it as a web project.

Therefore, when I create a server inside my eclipse workspace, and go to the dialog where I select what projects to deploy to my server, I am not offered to deploy my newly created project.

Ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should explicitly mention in your pom.xml that the maven-eclipse-plugin should generate a WTP-project. A simple example, which should be in your pom.xml at the build-part, would be:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <wtpmanifest>true</wtpmanifest>
            <wtpapplicationxml>true</wtpapplicationxml>
            <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0` to generate all WTP meta-data for the project without changing the POM.

Of course, you'd have to change the WTP version if you are using an older version of Eclipse.

Comment: But doesn't this interfere with the m2e plugin for eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

Just install a development version of m2eclipse and your project will be used as a maven project, no need to do mvn eclipse:eclipse or anything like that. I use it and works.

http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/

Answer (score 0):

Did you jump from the create command to the eclipse:eclipse command?

Check out [this link](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-webapp.html). You need to edit your POM first, then call "mvn clean package". After you do that, THEN try the "mvn eclipse:eclipse".

Comment: My comment was from 7 years ago. I have a feeling that it no longer would apply with all the changes