# Eclipse is constantly redeploying my web project to tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, maven

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185603/a-java-web-project-created-with-maven-is-not-recognized-as-such-by-eclipse) (in short: I have created a web project with maven and I am deploying it to tomcat with eclipse).

Eclipse is redeploying and redploying my project non stop. The project seems to work, but this is very annoying. At the beggining I thought that eclipse is eagerly deploying the project after my edits, but it happens even if I don't touch the keyboard.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In servers tab double click on your server.  The config page should open.  Now click on the modules tab in that page.  Select the web module from the table in that tab and edit it.  De-select "Auto Reloading Enabled" there.

Answer (score 0):

Some file inside your Eclipse project is been changed constantly. Are you sure that your webapp isn't constantly updating some file which is located in for example the project's webcontent?

Comment: not true, I thought the same as you, but turns out that @Chandru is right

Comment: That's a workaround, not a solution. Now you can't do hotedits/hotdeploys anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I had to disable "Build Automatically" (under Project menu) to get this to stop.  Thankfully it is easy to turn back on when I need to ensure that my workspace is fully built.

I suspect the 'why' has to do with eclipse's building of the project, vs maven's building of 'target'.  The time stamps are never the same, so Eclipse tries to build again to catch up.