# STS/Eclipse "Java EE" perspective does not recognise maven directory structure

Tags: eclipse, maven

I'm new to maven and I am trying to get eclipse to recognise the maven directory structure when i'm using the dynamic web project perspective.

So I started with the question here: [A Java web project created with Maven is not recognized as such by Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185603/a-java-web-project-created-with-maven-is-not-recognized-as-such-by-eclipse) and I got this far:

- I edited the eclipse-plugin in my pom.xml as:

  ```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <wtpmanifest>true</wtpmanifest>
          <wtpapplicationxml>true</wtpapplicationxml>
          <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>             
          <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
          <additionalBuildcommands>
            <buildcommand>com.atlassw.tools.eclipse.checkstyle.CheckstyleBuilder</buildcommand>
          </additionalBuildcommands>
          <additionalConfig>
            <file>
              <name>.checkstyle</name>
              <url>http://rs.gbif.org/conventions/java-style-config.xml</url>
            </file>
          </additionalConfig>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
  ```
- Then I used the command

  ```
  mvn eclipse:eclipse
  ```

and it gave the following as output:

```
     [INFO] Scanning for projects...
     [INFO]
     [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     [INFO] Building IPT 2.0.3-SNAPSHOT
     [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     [INFO]
     [INFO] >>> maven-eclipse-plugin:2.6:eclipse (default-cli) @ ipt >>>
     [INFO]
     [INFO] --- buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-4:create (default) @ ipt ---
     [INFO] Checking for local modifications: skipped.
     [INFO] Updating project files from SCM: skipped.
     [INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "svn --non-interactive info"
     [INFO] Working directory: C:\IOR_SVN\gbif-providertoolkit-read-only\gbif-ipt
     [INFO] Storing buildNumber: 3391 at timestamp: 1309767247372
     [INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "svn --non-interactive info"
     [INFO] Working directory: C:\IOR_SVN\gbif-providertoolkit-read-only\gbif-ipt
     [INFO] Storing buildScmBranch: trunk
     [INFO]
     [INFO] <<< maven-eclipse-plugin:2.6:eclipse (default-cli) @ ipt <<<
     [INFO]
     [INFO] --- maven-eclipse-plugin:2.6:eclipse (default-cli) @ ipt ---
     [INFO] Adding support for WTP version 2.0.
     [INFO] Using Eclipse Workspace: null
     [INFO] Adding default classpath container: org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAIN
     ER
     [WARNING] Invalid POM for org.apache.struts:struts2-core:jar:2.0.5, transitive d
     ependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more detail
     s
     [INFO] @@@ TRUE - Manifests are equal
     [INFO] Not writing Manifest file as it is unchanged: C:\IOR_SVN\gbif-providertoo
     lkit-read-only\gbif-ipt\src\main\webapp\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF
     [INFO] Wrote settings to C:\IOR_SVN\gbif-providertoolkit-read-only\gbif-ipt\.set
     tings\org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
     [INFO] Wrote Eclipse project for "ipt" to C:\IOR_SVN\gbif-providertoolkit-read-o
     nly\gbif-ipt.
```

So doing this method I get the my Java Folders recognized in the "Java Perspective" in eclipse, but when I go to the "Java EE" perspective then nothing is recognized there. So the source as well as the webapps folder does not get recognised.

In terms of versions, I use the SpringSource IDE version 2.3.1 and I use version 3 of maven (this version didn't come with maven prebundled so I downloaded the latest maven)

Comment: Are you using the m2eclipse plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen this happen when you run eclipse:eclipse command, some of the eclipse project facets properties on eclipse are changing, To verify this do this in eclipse

Select the project ==> properties ==> Project Facets ==> Dynamic Web Module (facets property)

I think that property check box is not checked (hence eclipse won't recognize your web project)

Comment: The Dynamic Web Module facet is checked. Although if i change my workspace and then import the same project then the "Java EE perspective" is correctly shown.