# WTP dependency does not seem to be working

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-3, m2eclipse, m2e

From reading [A Java web project created with Maven is not recognized as such by Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185603/a-java-web-project-created-with-maven-is-not-recognized-as-such-by-eclipse)

I add the below plugin to pom.xml to convert my maven project to a web project :

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <wtpmanifest>true</wtpmanifest>
            <wtpapplicationxml>true</wtpapplicationxml>
            <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugin>
```

I then run "Update Project Configuration" but the maven project is not converted to a web project.

If I run the command `mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0` the project is then updated. Should updating the .pom file not suffice to convert the maven project to a web project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not suffice.  The plugin configuration needs to be executed, which will not happen by just loading/refreshing it in Eclipse.  It gets executed when `mvn eclipse:eclipse` is run.

I assume we do not have [m2e](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/), which does not need this configuration anway.

Comment: I do have m2e, but to deploy to tomcat I need to convert the project to a web project so why dont I need this configuration ?

Comment: @user470184. m2e does not use information in maven-eclipse-plugin. It auto-detects project based on `packaging` type.  You would want to have m2e wtp integration installed.

Comment: Are m2e & maven-eclipse-plugin not the same plugin ?

Comment: @user470184. No. They are mutually exclusive.  They do not work well with each other as well.

Comment: @user470184. Found this related [blog entry](http://blog.teamextension.com/m2eclipse-m2e-support-for-maven-eclipse-plugin-projects-497).

Comment: I should have read the maven-eclipse-plugin description - "An Eclipse plug-in for generating Eclipse IDE files, like .classpath, .project, etc. Often confused with M2Eclipse." I'm not actually using the "Maven Eclipse Plugin". I'm just using m2e, but I still need to convert the maven project to web project to run the project with tomcat ?

Comment: @user470184. Install m2e, wtp support for m2e.  Remove maven-eclipse-plugin configuration from pom, remove existing eclipse configuration, import into Eclipse as maven project.

Comment: I have installed m2e. But when I "import into Eclipse as maven project" I am unable to add the project to tomcat as its not a web project. This is why I initially used the "maven-eclipse-plugin". How do I add wtp support for m2e ?